# Random IP accessing webserver

Tags: java, html, ip, webserver

I am currently studying a computer communications at university, and hence have a extremely basic web server running on an old laptop. I was working on it today and a random ip was accessing it requesting files.

I have the ip and when i tracked it (on a website not sure if its trustworthy but i was curious http://www.iptrackeronline.com/index.php?ip_address=115.230.125.146) and it says its from china. (Which is Weird because i'm from New Zealand and i made the server 2-3 days ago not disclosing the ip or anything to anyone).

Just wondering if its dangerous to other devices on the same network to have whoever it is searching around. (It doesn't matter to me what theyre doing on the laptop as it has a fresh ubuntu install and has nothing on it but a small bit of java code)

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're on the university network, it's most likely protected and should limit access to other files. I would recommend running the web server as a different user with different permissions so that it limits access to not only the network, but also other files on the system.

Comment: The server is on a home network on an old laptop, sorry should have specified that better